# Display Tag: Exporting data to excel and pdf

Tags: java, struts2, displaytag

I am facing problem while trying to export data from a display tag table to excel or pdf. The problem is that when I export to excel, nothing but the column names appear. And when I export to pdf nothing appears (blank page).

I am using display-tag 1.2, commons-beanutils 1.7.0, commons-collections 3.2, commons-lang 2.3, commons-logging 1.0.4, itext 1.3 and office 2007 & adobe reader 8 (if these matter).

I dont think that I need to show the code because I dont think there is any problem there as the display tag is handling everything itself. The only thing that I have done is the displaytag.properties (although I dont think that is the problem, because without that also the problem persists). Still the displaytag.properties file is :

```
export.pdf=true
export.csv=false
export.xml=false
export.pdf.class=org.displaytag.export.DefaultPdfExportView
export.excel.filename=data.xls
export.pdf.filename=data.pdf
```

Please advise as to where the problem could lie. If you feel that I should share some more code, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome for that 
add another attribute in display tag **requestURI="#"** with same reference